# Adding bootstrap modal destroys topbar layout and header

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I am pretty new to this, I simply want that if someone clicks on a text like "size chart" to open an image in a modal. I added the modal to the product page, and the topbar and header logo only change on the products page, on every other page they look like they should
If I use this code, the modal works, but the modal style somehow destroys parts of my topbar and header logo.

Can you please help me?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >Size chart</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vmatechs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
```

[image: changes]

Comment: What topbar and header logo?

Comment: Might be more helpful to show the html for your navbar/header area.

Comment: I added the modal to the product page, and the topbar and header logo only change on the products page, on every other page they look like they should

Answer (score 0):

The text of your button is wrong, you need to change, "`<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >Size chart</a>`" to be, "`<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >Size chart</a>`". Notice I changed "href=" to be "data-toggle=" this is because leaving it as href makes the page think that is still an active link, however when you change it to Bootstraps' data-target method it simply calls via JS, this is the only problem I see in this snippet.

Comment: Hi, I change the line with the data toggle but nothing changed. What do you mean to bootstraps data target?

Comment: Bootstrap, in-order to properly work needs to have some of their own methods and functions. One such function needed to work is their data-target. Simply put bootstrap parses the file before the browser in turn running through and scanning to see if there are any extra functions being named and called. So when you put "data-target" within you <a> tags it will mark to Bootstrap that it and where it is needs to be treated differently. Bootstrap then says, "Oh, data-target? Ok, I'll take that." and it takes it and pumps out a nice modal-enabled link that focuses on the modal who's ID is the same.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. The modal in fact works like it should work, the only remaining problem is, that it kind of blows up the setting of my topbar and header when you are on the product page. Do you have a clue what I can do about that?

Comment: Hi Questa, sorry for such a late reply-work (rip) I'm not sure I know what you mean, if you could include a screenshot of the issue and some of the code I may be able to help you out more. Unless you've already solved the issue!

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have added the picture in the opening post.

Comment: If this issue only happens after the modal has been opened I would assume that there is some inline styling that is not being initialized after the modal has been closed. An example of how to fix this is to ensure that the modal is the only thing affecting the nav bar *aka take the modal out, click everything*. Then instead of having any inline styles, use external css. Also maybe add some padding to the nav bar to make it a bit more flexible as the modal will flex the page some, so maybe padding-bottom of 17px or something like that. I hope this is clear, haven't had my coffee yet.